# Moved Wordpress to a subdirectory, don't want site-url to redirect to my subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, redirect, root, subdirectory

I've searched a while but couldn't find an answer to this question yet. I had WP originally installed in the site root and moved it to a subfolder and went through the common steps necessary. I do this because I want to run wordpress only for blogging reasons and keep another HTML site as my main project that I want to access through my domain `www.example.com` and the wordpress blog through `www.example.com/blog/`

I moved the WP system therefore to `/blog` and changed the site address and wp address to that folder and followed the usual steps. Everything works just fine. Still when I enter my domain it redirects automatically to the `/blog` subdirectory and not to the site that lies in the root that has a `index.html`. There is no `.htaccess` file in the root or anything similar. How is that possible? Happy about all suggestions.

Comment: .htaccess is hidden by default. From your console, run `ls -al` to make sure it is not really there.

Comment: Thanks but I guess thats not the problem. I can see the htaccess file of WP in the subfolder via FTP and also via Filemanager. I have no access over a console I guess, as I use a one.com package.